# how to convert array object into array csv kind of type

Tags: javascript

I have this array object and I want to try convert it to like array for csv file kind of type. For example like array object bellow

```
const arrayObject = [
  {
    Name: "Alex",
    Age: 16,
    Address: "Miami",
  },
  {
    Name: "James",
    Age: 36,
    Address: "LA",
  },
  {
    Name: "Mark",
    Age: 25,
    Address: "San Diego",
  },
];
```

and what I expect to converted to look like this:

```
 [
    'Name,Age,Address',
    'Alex,16,Miami',
    'James,36,LA',
    'Mark,25,San Diego'

  ]
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this? Or what are your thoughts on this. This helps us to help you better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use these functions.
Object.keys(), Object.values(), Array.map(), Array.filter()

```js
const arrayObject = [{
    Name: 'Alex',
    Age: 16,
    Address: 'Miami'
  },
  {
    Name: 'James',
    Age: 36,
    Address: 'LA'
  },
  {
    Name: 'Mark',
    Age: 25,
    Address: 'San Diego',
  }
]

const newKeyArray = arrayObject.map(item => Object.keys(item).toString()).filter((item, index, self) => self.indexOf(item) === index);

const newValueArray = arrayObject.map(item => Object.values(item).toString());

const result = newKeyArray.concat(newValueArray);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let data = [{ Name: 'Alex', Age: 16, Address: 'Miami' }, { Name: 'James', Age: 36, Address: 'LA' }, { Name: 'Mark', Age: 25, Address: 'San Diego',
}]

console.log(

  [
    Object.keys(data[0]).join(','),
    ...data.map(itm => Object.values(itm).join(','))
  ]

)
```

Comment: You're missing the headings.

Answer (score 0):

Map the arrayObject variable and return the values as a string. This will work for any other properties you add.

```js
const arrayObject = [{
    Name: 'Alex',
    Age: 16,
    Address: 'Miami'
  },
  {
    Name: 'James',
    Age: 36,
    Address: 'LA'
  },
  {
    Name: 'Mark',
    Age: 25,
    Address: 'San Diego',
  }
]
const newArray = arrayObject.map(item => {
  return Object.values(item).toString();
});

console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: You're missing the headings.

Answer (score 0):

Get the keys using `Object.keys` and the values using `Object.values` and then use concat to merge them into the final result.

```js
const arrayObject = [{
    Name: 'Alex',
    Age: 16,
    Address: 'Miami'
},
{
    Name: 'James',
    Age: 36,
    Address: 'LA'
},
{
    Name: 'Mark',
    Age: 25,
    Address: 'San Diego',
}];

const keys = Object.keys(arrayObject[0]);
const values = arrayObject.map(item =>  Object.values(item)).toString().split(',');

const res = keys.concat(values);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create some headings from the first object's [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).
2. [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array and for each object return its [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) (an array), and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array up into a comma-delimited string.
3. Combine the headings and the mapped data into a new array.

```js
const arr=[{Name:'Alex',Age:16,Address:'Miami'},{Name:'James',Age:36,Address:'LA'},{Name:'Mark',Age:25,Address:'San Diego'}];

const headings = Object.keys(arr[0]).join(',');

const rows = arr.map(obj => {
  return Object.values(obj).join(',');
});

const csv = [headings, ...rows];

console.log(csv);
```